# java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Unsupported feature

Tags: java, sql

am new to java am using eclipseLunaIDE, i have some problem with this code, tried to run this program with differnet version of ojdbc jars but still this problem doesnt resolve

```
PreparedStatement prepareStatement = conn.prepareStatement("insert into stu values(?,?)");
prepareStatement.setInt(1, 1);
prepareStatement.setString(2, "AAA");
prepareStatement.addBatch();

prepareStatement.setInt(1, 20);
prepareStatement.setString(2, "A");
prepareStatement.addBatch();

prepareStatement.addBatch("insert into stu values(?,?)"); *//exception occurs at this line*,
prepareStatement.setInt(1, 20);
prepareStatement.setString(2, "A");
prepareStatement.addBatch();
```

Comment: Could you specify driver and show exavt Exception? I'd guess batchibg us not supported so you'd have to replace addBatch with executeUpdate

Comment: in which statement are you getting the exception? can you add stack trace to the original post?

Comment: Show us error you getting.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Unsupported feature
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.addBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:11957)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.addBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:318)
 at com.vk.db.BatchProcessing.main(BatchProcessing.java:32)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prepareStatement.addBatch("insert into stu values(?,?)"); *//exception occurs at this line*,

That line is unneeded (statement is already prepared) and causing the error. You just set the parameter 1 and 2 and addBatch and do it again before calling updateBatch () after last addBatch.

addBatch  () takes no arguments. It adds the prepared statement (with parameters set so far) into the batch.

```
PreparedStatement prepareStatement = conn.prepareStatement("insert into stu values(?,?)");
prepareStatement.setInt(1, 1);
prepareStatement.setString(2, "AAA");
prepareStatement.addBatch();

prepareStatement.setInt(1, 20);
prepareStatement.setString(2, "A");
prepareStatement.addBatch();

prepareStatement.executeBatch();
```

Once those inserts are done (by executing the batch) you might want to continue with updates or whatever.

Comment: prepareStatement.addBatch("update stu set name='?' where rollno=?");   even when am using this line  at same place, same exception occurs,

Comment: so how to add DML commands to batch for an prepared statement??

Comment: Thank you so much for the needy help